# Sharepoint document library Icon with overlay (linkdocument) Works in one list but not the other

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am not a SharePoint developer but the last week i have been working on a integration thingy with SharePoint for one of our Products. I Appreciate all the help i can get.

I Have a service that creates linkdocuments in SharePoint. The documents are saved to different document lists.The link file looks like the following:

```
public string RedirectAspxPage(string ext) {
        var builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.Append("<%@ Assembly Name='Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' %>");
        builder.Append("<%@ Register TagPrefix='SharePoint' Namespace='Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls' Assembly='Microsoft.SharePoint' %>");
        builder.Append("<%@ Import Namespace='System.IO' %>");
        builder.Append("<%@ Import Namespace='Microsoft.SharePoint' %>");
        builder.Append("<%@ Import Namespace='Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities' %>");
        builder.Append("<%@ Import Namespace='Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls' %>");
        builder.Append("<html xmlns:mso=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office\" xmlns:msdt=\"uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882\">");
        builder.Append("<head>");
        builder.Append("<meta name=\"WebPartPageExpansion\" content=\"full\" /> <meta name='progid' content='SharePoint.Link' /> ");
        builder.Append("<!--[if gte mso 9]><SharePoint:CTFieldRefs runat=server Prefix=\"mso:\" FieldList=\"FileLeafRef,URL\"><xml>");
        builder.Append("<mso:CustomDocumentProperties>");
        builder.Append("<mso:ContentTypeId msdt:dt=\"string\">0x01010A00772E34FDFA9F4BC68135CD6CC9055E82</mso:ContentTypeId>");
        builder.Append("<mso:IconOverlay msdt:dt=\"string\">|" + ext + "|linkoverlay.gif</mso:IconOverlay>");
        builder.Append("<mso:URL msdt:dt=\"string\">{0}, {0}</mso:URL>");
        builder.Append("</mso:CustomDocumentProperties>");
        builder.Append("</xml></SharePoint:CTFieldRefs><![endif]-->");
        builder.Append("</head>");
        builder.Append("<body>");
        builder.Append("<form id='Form1' runat='server'>");
        builder.Append("<SharePoint:UrlRedirector id='Redirector1' runat='server' />");
        builder.Append("</form>");
        builder.Append("</body>");
        builder.Append("</html>");
        return builder.ToString();
    }
```

The input parameter ext contains the file extension for example: pdf or docx or txt etc.
The redirectpage is saved to the document list by:

```
string redirectAspx = RedirectAspxPage(originalExtension);
redirectAspx = redirectAspx.Replace("{0}", DocumentUrl);
var file = list.RootFolder.Files.Add(documentName, UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(redirectAspx));
```

The parameter "documentName" that gets added to the list allways ends with ".aspx"

Now to the actual problem.
For one document list everything works perfect. In the list the document rows are displayed with the correct Icon for the file extension and also the overlay link Icon (tried to have a screenshot but dont have 10 rep Points yet).

For all other document libraries I only get the overlay Icon for each document row.

The markup for the Icon TD in the lists that does not work:

```
<TD class=ms-vb-icon>
<IMG title=delux.aspx alt=delux.aspx src="/_layouts/images/DOCLINK.GIF" border=0>
</TD>
```

The markup the the Icon TD in the list that works:

```
<TD class=ms-vb-icon>
<IMG title="ewf.aspx" alt="ewf.aspx" src="/_layouts/images/icdocx.png" border=0>
<IMG title="" class=ms-vb-icon-overlay alt="" src="/_layouts/images/linkoverlay.gif">
</TD>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a special field in SPListItem called IconOverlay that you should to set equal to "linkoverlay.gif".
When you create link to a document manually through interface it is added to the library by SharePoint code if it not exists. Until you have that field in library it will not be resolved correctly.